# Save temporary output as dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop

I am trying to add a new column to multiple dataframes in the environment. I have first tried the following code, which does not work.

```
list_var <- names(test)

for (i in list_var){

for (i in list_var){

assign(paste0("tris_plat_", i), as.data.frame(wtd.table(test[[i]], weights = Ech_final_nom_SD$pond, useNA= "always")))
  
paste0("tris_plat_", i, "$", "Pourcentage") <- get(paste0("tris_plat_", i))[, 2] / sum(get(paste0("tris_plat_", i))[, 2])

}
}
```

After reading different posts on the topic I have tried this solution which works but only creates the output I want and does not replace the original dataframes in the environment. How can I achieve this?

```
df_list <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

add.column <-  function(dataframe){
      dataframe$Pourcentage <- dataframe[,2]/ sum(dataframe[,2])
      dataframe
}

lapply(df_list, add.column)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess writing my question down made me think a little harder. Here is the solution :

`list2env(lapply(df_list, add.column), envir = .GlobalEnv)`